# "E: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265" while installing VLC

Tags: apt, vlc

I tried installing VLC using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

and it is showing this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Answer (score 0):

vlc-plugin-libde265 is not available in the Ubuntu repositories as can be seen at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=vlc-plugin-libde265. To install it, you have to add the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~strukturag/+archive/ubuntu/libde265:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Comment: Sadly I get this bernie `E: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265`

Answer (score 0):

**Vlc is available from the default repository.**  The library of your error message isn't (`vlc-plugin-libde265`).  You're having problems with a particular `PPA` or other sources that you have installed that doesn't have the supported libraries available on your system, or the default repository.

**You can resolve the issue and install Vlc** by purging what you already have installed, removing the broken PPA, then installing the default with these commands:

```
$ sudo apt --purge vlc*
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install vlc
```

You can remove the broken PPA with these commands:

```
$ sudo apt install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge [ppaname]
$ sudo apt update
```